# Assume view state with Espresso test

Tags: android, junit, junit4, functional-testing, android-espresso

JUnit library has an `Assume.*` instructions like `Assume.assumeTrue(boolean)` which works like assertions, but not cause test to fail and just to been ignored.

I want to perform such checking in `arrange` part of test for one of my views, by example assume, that founded checkbox is checked before starting the `act` part of test.

Take a look:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void deselectFilter_AllFiltersSelected_CheckboxAllSelectedUnchecked() {
    //arrange
    ViewInteraction checkBox = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.cbCheckAll), isDisplayed()));

    //assume that this checkbox is checked 

    //act
    ...
    //assert
    ...
}
```

In the `arrange` part i've received not a `View`, but `ViewInteraction`.
So I can perform such `assertion` like `checkBox.check(matches(isChecked()))`
But how to perform assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom `ViewAssertion` to assume that no `Exception` is thrown when Espresso `ViewMatcher` fails:

```
public static ViewAssertion assume(final Matcher<? super View> viewMatcher) {
    return new ViewAssertion() {
        @Override
        public void check(final View view, final NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
            try {
                ViewAssertions.matches(viewMatcher).check(view, noViewFoundException);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Assume that there is no exception
                Assume.assumeNoException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use that assertion to assume like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.cbCheckAll)).check(assume(isChecked()));
```

Comment: Thanks. This could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've founded at this moment is just finding assuming view manually with activity from test rule. And then assume via jUnit.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cbCheckAll);
Assume.assumeTrue(checkBox.isChecked());
```

If you know a better way, maybe with using Espresso, please answer. Seems that it impossible to access view directly from Espresso commands